# pop() function implementation in a Linked List (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++98

I'm overall kind of confused about the idea of linked lists. So I'm trying to implement some functions to help me understand.

```
struct Node {
  string val;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};

struct Stew {
  Node* first;
  Node* last;
};
```

So here, Stew has special pointers to the front element and the last element.

I'm trying to remove the first element (pop).

So I attempted it as follows, and I can't seem to find what the error in it is:

```
void pop (Stew& q) {
  assert (!isEmpty(q));
  q.first = q.first->next;
  q.first -> prev = NULL;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

By the way, I'm currently using C++98, not C++11.

Comment: What tells you this is wrong? Do you get compile-time / run-time errors or is the behaviour not correct, in what cases is it not correct?

Comment: Is there some reason you are not encapsulating the `pop` function within your linked list class?

Comment: note that a `pop` function should remove the first item from the list and **return** it, right now you are just losing this item, having no pointer to it and no way to use it or free the memory it uses.

Comment: The behaviour isn't right.

Comment: @user3358732 Is it always wrong or only in specific cases and what does wrongly happen?

Comment: @RonTeller does it not just return a stack with the first element removed? So returning the first element itself is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to free the memory of the deleted node with `delete` and you didn't take care of the case that the list is exactly one element long. Because if that is the case then after

```
q.first = q.first->next;
```

`q.first` is `NULL`. Then you try to dereference `q.first` in the next line:

```
q.first -> prev = NULL;
```

Don't do that step if the list was original one element long and is afterwards empty. Instead take care of `q.last` which won't be pointing to allocated memory anymore:

```
q.first = q.first->next;
if(q.first)
    q.first->prev = NULL;
else
    q.last = NULL;
```

(Although depending on the implementation of the rest of the linked list the else block won't be necessary, because the information whether the list is empty is fully contained in either `q.last` or `q.first`)

Also `pop` usually returns the removed value. Your `pop` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized you have implemented a `last` pontier to your `Stew` class so you can:

```
struct Node {
  string val;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};

struct Stew {
  Node* first;
  Node* last;
};


typedef struct Node node_t;
typedef struct Stew stew_t;

node_t* pop(stew_t& q)
{
    node_t* last = q->last;
    if (q->last == q->first)        // List is empty or has only one element.
    {
        q->first = NULL;
        q->last = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
         q->last = last->prev;     // Update the last pointer.
    }

    return last;
}
```